# get data from multiple tables in multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a social script but I got a little trouble while retrieving posts of mine and my friends from posts table and user avatar from users table
I can get all posts of myself or only from my friends not mine. how may I get all posts of mine and my friends and profile picture of the user who added post

```
$all_friends = array();
$sql = "SELECT user1 FROM friends WHERE user2='$u' AND accepted='1' ORDER BY RAND() ";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($all_friends, $row["user1"]);
}
$sql = "SELECT user2 FROM friends WHERE user1='$u' AND accepted='1' ORDER BY RAND()";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($all_friends, $row["user2"]);
}

$orLogic = '';
foreach($all_friends as $key => $user){
        $orLogic .= "username='$user' OR ";
}
$orLogic = chop($orLogic, "OR ");
$sql = "SELECT username, avatar FROM users WHERE $orLogic";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $fusername = $row["username"];
    $favatar = $row["avatar"];
    if($favatar != ""){
        $fpic = 'user/'.$fusername.'/'.$favatar.'';
    } else {
        $fpic = 'img/male.png';
    }
```

this is my friends code using $fusername I can get all their posts but how may I get my posts to

Comment: All those `username = x OR username = y ...` can be combined into `username IN (x, y, ...)`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is the `posts` table in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work.  But maybe try combining the 3 SQL statements into 1?

```
SELECT friends.user1 as user, users.avatar
FROM friends
INNER JOIN users ON users.username = friends.user1
WHERE friends.user2 = '$u' AND friends.accepted = '1'
UNION
SELECT friends.user2 as user, users.avatar
FROM friends
INNER JOIN users ON users.username = friends.user1
WHERE friends.user1 = '$u' AND friends.accepted = '1'    
ORDER BY RAND()
```